# Is possible to access google drive user data through admin account?

Tags: rest, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I am trying use Google Drive Rest API. My use case is, I have a google domain with some users and one admin. And I need to access and manipulate all users data from admin account. 
Is it possible? 
If possible can any one say how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Service Account to authorize your requests. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) you can find a guide that explains how. I'd recommend reading the documentation carefully as using service accounts may be quite dangerous.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/483967/raz3r

And I have some issues regarding this. 

Can you explain How service accounts are dangerous?
Is there any solution for my problem without using service accounts?

Thanks in advance.